# FPGA Filter Project

Tags: filter, project, fpga

Do you guys have any good ideas on FPGA projects involving a filter? I want to do something interesting... not sure what. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2):

Aloha!

As an alternative you could look at implementing some audio filter effects. The I/O requirements are easier than video. This means that you can focus on the effects themeselves and also create a stand alone (board) demo for your peers and teachers to try out.

As an example, look at the Cubase64 by Pex Tufvesson. A really sweet example of constrained implementations of audio effects algorithms. There is a good paper as well as a source code available:

http://www.livet.se/mahoney/c64-files/Cubase64_White_Paper_by_Pex_Mahoney_Tufvesson.pdf

Your task would be to implement one or more of these in HW instead of in SW. How about implementing a few and have switches toggle them on and off for user controlled effects?

You would get a pipeline with ADC interace followed by one or more effect blocks, each of which would have a bypass/enable controlled by an external switch. The pipeline would end with the DAC interface.

A simple design with littre overhead control which would clearly (audible) demo the implemented effects.

Hmmm, I think I should do this myself. ;-)

If you want to here Cubase64 there is a movie on YouTube:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTGkf21UpJ8

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea - implement a fast image histogram routine in FPGA. It could just take 8 bit input data and update a 256 bin histogram. You'd also need a way of zeroing the histogram at the start and a way to read the contents of the 256 bins afterwards. This is a potentially useful application as histogramming is a very common operation in image processing and it is inherently bottlenecked on general purpose CPUs due to serial dependencies. It can also not easily be vectorized with SIMD. A fast FPGA implementation would therefore offer real advantages over a software implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I always find image processing projects are great - you can *see* results on a screen, not just pretty graphs, but actual processed imagery.  Get an FPGA board with a camera input and VGA output.  Try implementing a [Sobel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator) filter first, graduate to a corner detector like [Harris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Harris_.26_Stephens_.2F_Plessey_corner_detection_algorithm) or [Shi Tomasi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Shi_and_Tomasi_corner_detection_algorithm) after that.